# Input in plugin widget does not allow spaces

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, forms

I'm developing a plugin for a client which allows keeping records of reservations to their hotel, and it has a widget which allows clients to make reservations. However, for some reason one of the fields in the widget `<input type="text" name="res_name" id="res_name" />` doesn't allow spaces, and I'm honestly stuck here.

This is the code that renders the widget:

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

/**
 * Adds Res_Widget widget.
 */
class Res_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'reservations_widget', // Base ID
            __( 'Reservations', 'text_domain' ), // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'A Reservation making widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
            );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). $args['after_title'];
        }
        $html = '<div class="reservation_module_widget">';
        $html .= '<h2>' . __('Reservations', 'text_domain') . '</h2>';
        $html .= '<form name="reservation_widget" method="post" id="res_form" action="">';
        $html .= '<div class="res_form-row">';
        $html .= '<div class="res_form-group">';
        $html .= '<label for="res_arrival">';
        $html .= __('Arrival', 'text_domain');
        $html .= '</label>';
        $html .= '<input name="arrival" type="date" id="res_arrival"/>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="res_form-group">';
        $html .= '<label for="res_checkout">';
        $html .= __('Checkout', 'text_domain');
        $html .= '</label>';
        $html .= '<input name="checkout" type="date" id="res_checkout" disabled />';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="res_form-row" id="room_data"></div>';
        $html .= '<div class="res_form-row">';
        $html .= '<div class="res_form-group hidden" data-hidden="true">';
        $html .= '<label for="res_name">';
        $html .= __('Name', 'text_domain');
        $html .= '</label>';
        $html .= '<input name="res_name" id="res_name" type="text" />';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="res_form-group hidden" data-hidden="true">';
        $html .= '<label for="res_email">';
        $html .= __('Email', 'text_domain');
        $html .= '</label>';
        $html .= '<input name="email" id="res_email" type="email" />';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="res_form-row"><div class="res_form-group">';
        $html .= '<input type="submit" value="'. __('Confirm Reservation', 'text_domain') .'"/>';
        $html .= '</div></div>';
        $html .= '<div id="form_errors"></div>';
        $html .= '</form>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        echo $html;
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
        </p>
        <?php 
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

        return $instance;
    }

} 

function register_res_widget() {
    register_widget("Res_Widget");
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_res_widget' );

/**/
```

Rendered Form:

```
<div class="reservation_module_widget">
<h2>Reservations</h2>
<form name="reservation_widget" method="post" id="res_form" action="">
<div class="res_form-row">
<div class="res_form-group">
<label for="res_arrival">Arrival</label>
<input name="arrival" type="date" id="res_arrival">
</div>
<div class="res_form-group">
<label for="res_checkout">Checkout</label>
<input name="checkout" type="date" id="res_checkout" disabled="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="res_form-row" id="room_data"></div>
<div class="res_form-row">
<div class="res_form-group hidden" data-hidden="true">
<label for="res_name">Name</label>
<input name="res_name" id="res_name" type="text">
</div>
<div class="res_form-group hidden" data-hidden="true">
<label for="res_email">Email</label>
<input name="email" id="res_email" type="email">
</div>
</div>
<div class="res_form-row">
<div class="res_form-group">
<input type="submit" value="Confirm Reservation">
</div>
</div>
<div id="form_errors"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

This is the js code that handles the form

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="checkout"]', function(){
        if (this.value!='' && this.value > $('input[name="arrival"]').val()){
            var arrival = $('input[name="arrival"]').val(),
            checkout = this.value;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: ajaxfilter.ajaxurl,
                data: {action:'reservationManagement', arrival:arrival, checkout:checkout, type:'client'},
                success: function(result){
                    try{
                        var rooms = JSON.parse(result);
                        var select = '';
                        var options = '';
                        rooms.forEach(function(room){
                            options += '<option value="' + room.id + '">' + room.name + '</option>';
                        });
                        select = '<div class="res_form-group">';
                        select += '<label for="res_room">Room</label>';
                        select += '<select name="res_room" id="res_room">';
                        select += options;
                        select += '</select>';
                        select += '</div>';


                        if(rooms.length>0){
                            if($('#res_room').length > 0){
                                $('#res_room').html(options);
                            } else{
                                $('#room_data').append(select);
                                $('.res_form-group[data-hidden]').removeClass('hidden');
                            }
                        }
                    } catch(e){
                        $('#room_data').html('');
                        $('.res_form-group[data-hidden]').addClass('hidden');
                        $('#form_errors').html('<p>'+result+'</p>');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#form_errors').html('');
                        }, 4000);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else{
            console.log('invalid');
        }
    });
```

Comment: What happens when you try to enter a name with spaces?

Comment: Nothing, same if I try to navigate the text within the input using the arrows

Comment: Is this a standard widget class? Are you using a sanitize method anywhere?

Comment: @Welcher Yeah, I just updated the code to include the full widget class, no sanitize methods that I know of, first time making a widget so there's probably something I missed or didn't know about

Comment: Can you post the code where you get the form data and save it? I mean the form you show in the widget in the frontend, not the form to create/configure the widget in the admin area, which is the code you have posted already.

Comment: @cybmeta just updated the question, added the rendered form and the javascript that handles it